# How can I "Quick Look" (result of pressing Space Bar in Finder) a filename printed by "ls" in iTerm2?

Tags: terminal, command-line, iterm, quicklook

Simple question: is it possible to get the "Quick Look" of images and text files by clicking the results of `ls` in an iTerm2 window?

Answer (score 1):

Can't find any relevant documentation anywhere, and this does not seem to work Terminal, but this is possible.

On my machine (macOS Sierra), I can **triple-click** a filename or folder after calling `ls` in iTerm2, and the Quick Look window pops up. Very neat!

Comment: You can adjust this behavior in iTerm2 in the Preferences/Pointer section.